# Coverage.py suggests I need to test for an ImportError -- how do I do that?

Tags: python, django, coverage.py

Just started using [coverage.py](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/) and am on a testing binge!

At the top of one my python files I have the following (which is used to account for differing versions of Django):

```
try: # newer versions
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey 
except ImportError: # older versions
    from django.contrib.contenttypes.generic import GenericForeignKey
```

When I run `coverage.py` it highlights the last two lines (the `except ImportError`) and flags it as needing a test.

*How do I test that in my unittests?*  Do I need to?  It doesn't seem that I should because I don't test all my other imports.  Is `coverage.py` just getting over excited?

Thanks~

Comment: It seems to me that you can try both import statements in shell to see if any of them works. None working means test failed.

Comment: @Mai - yes they do work; however, I want to put it in my unittest and am not sure how to code that.  from a functional standpoint they work.

Comment: Dependency should be checked not in test, but in runtime. You can wrap each of the import in module script in a try statement, and print message when each of them fails. Terminate the process gracefully when both failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to test that alternate import is to remember why you have that line of code in the first place.  The comment says, "older versions."  I'm guessing that means older versions of Django.  So you are supporting older versions, but it looks like you are not testing with them.

You should run your test suite on all of the versions of Django you support, or at least, the oldest and newest versions.  Then you can combine the coverage results from each of those runs.  If you do that, those lines will all be covered.

Comment: That definitely sounds like the correct answer to me.  In fact, I am using `tox` to run tests against multiple versions of Python and Django.  I will look at how to combine the runs using `coverage.py` -- it's obviously only showing me the last run.

Answer (score 1):

There are simple lines of code that sometimes really does not make sense to devote time and write a test specific for them. It may be that this piece of code falls into this category.

Therefore you can instruct coverage to ignore it by adding a `# pragma nocover` comment next to any live that you want to be excluded from coverage. Please note that adding this on a line that introduces a block (such as an `if` statement), it will excude the whole block.

Reference: [Excluding code from coverage](http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/excluding.html).

Comment: Thanks for the opinion as to whether I need to test it or not.  Appreciate it.  I'm hoping someone can also help show *how* to do it, regardless, in a unittest as well.

Comment: Welcome, I certainly understand. Tbh I am curious too.